# how to implement ArrayList with low memory system where memory blocks are available in small chunk but huge sequence of chunks are not available

Tags: java, memory-management

I have written my own ArrayList implementation such as

```
    ArrayList<T>
    {
    int capacity;
    int[] element_array;
    int size();
    boolean insert();
    boolean insertAtIndex();
    boolean remove(int element);
    boolean removeAtIndex(int index,int element);
    resize();
// when capacity is filled 75% , 
//create a new array with double size and relocate all element from existing array to new array
    }
```

and my implementation of resize creates a new array of double size.
now If I am dealing with small memory system , chances are memory has been allocated to several object and shall the need arise to double my array.
since the memory is low on system , memory might still be available to create an array of say a million size , but sequential memory is not available to be allocated .

How shall I deal with such situation ?

this is an hypothetical scenario but still would like to handle it .
suggestions/guidelines please .

or am I missing something with array memory allocation ?

Comment: I don't usually see it being discussed how the JVM actually allocates memory under the hood when expanding a collection. Can you elaborate on why this matters to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : i understand , this is only a hypothetical scenario , but should the need arise , i would like to know about the proficiency and adequacy of the data structure implementation , but still hypothetical .i have to write my own implementation to be deployed on systems with low memory .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list ?

Comment: Remember that Java uses garbage collection, so memory fragmentation isn't an issue you have to deal with.  When you ask to allocate _X_ amount of memory, Java will get it for you if it can.  All you have to worry about is what to do in case of the dreaded `OutOfMemoryException`, and your choices are basically 1) throw up your hands in defeat, or 2) try again but ask for less memory next time.

Comment: @KevinAnderson : option 2 is what i am proceeding  with currently , just wanted to know if there is better or other way , thanks

Answer (score 1):

A garbage collector thus has two mandates:

To quickly free unreferenced memory in order to satisfy an application's allocation rate so that it doesn't run out of memory.
To reclaim memory while minimally impacting the performance (e.g., latency and throughput) of a running application.

According to Garbage Collector's concept **Use Recycling techniques**

e.g

- Tracing collectors
- Mark-sweep collection
- Copying collection
- Incremental collection
- Conservative garbage collection
- Reference counts

to sort out sequential memory use the above techniques instead of TLAB(Thread Local Buffer Allocation) which is the risk of inducing memory inefficiency by fragmenting the heap.

For More Clarification use the given link thoroughly

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078645/java-se/jvm-performance-optimization-part-3-garbage-collection.html

Comment: i am more concerned about memory deficiency before GC kicks in , not practical , hypothetical scenario

Comment: You can utilize memory deficiency if you deallocate resources.